# Retrievel of data from Django Redis Cache is taking great amount of time

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework, redis

I'm trying to use Redis in caching my data so that DB calls are reduced. But the time taken for retrieval from cache is much large than the time which I'm getting when fetching the records without caching.

I'm trying to store the django queryset object which consist of around 28k+ records and it's only going to increase as the data increases in the Database.

I'm using
Django - 3.0
DRF - 3.10.3
django-redis - 4.12
redis - 3.5.3

CodeWise:

here is my `settings.py` for setting default cache

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': [
        f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/1',
        f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/2'
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.ShardClient',
        'CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS': {
            'max_connections': 100,
            'retry_on_timeout': True
        },
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD')
    }
}
```

`views.py`
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache.backends.base import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
from rest_framework.response import Response
CACHE_TTL = 60 * 1

```
class RecordsList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   __basic_fields = ('name', 'id')
   # queryset = Records.objects.all()
   serializer_class = RecordsNewSerializer
   http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
   filter_fields = __basic_fields
   search_fields = __basic_fields
   
   def get_queryset(self):
     if 'records' in cache:
        print('from cache')
        queryset = cache.get('records')        
     else:
        print("Saving to Cache")
        queryset = Records.objects.all()
        # queryset = queryset[1:5]
        cache.set('records', queryset, timeout=CACHE_TTL)

     return queryset
```

Here as you can see I'm saving the django queryset object into the Cache, Now when I'm reducing the object size to say just 100 records, the time taken to get these records is around `400ms` and for the entire data it is `3000ms+`. Can it be reduced as if I dont add the caching part I'm able to retrieve the entire data( 28k+ ) in around `600ms`. So When I add the caching it is increasing the time for the output. Is my approach to implement caching wrong?? If so can anyone help me to get it right by guiding me on the right track!!.

Comment: What data is in the Records object? The problem might be that when you run Records.objects.all() every object is going to be instantiated and process. This can explain why fetching all and putting it in cache, takes longer than without cache. Same can be when the cache is filled.. how long does it take to parse the cached contents back into instantiated objects? Which database are you using?

Comment: @DinoHensen I have a postgres DB, Yes when I run Records.objects.all(). It's going to fetch all the records from the table and Records contain  6 columns ( id, start_date,end_date,user_id,book_id,room_id). And when  I retrieve data from the cache it is taking around 3000 ms which is way more than if i try to do it without cache

Comment: It's hard to say without profiling your specific situation, but the django_redis uses Redis' SET operation. The client code has to encode all your data before sending it to Redis' SET command. When you retrieve that data, it has to decode (optional decompress and deserialize) all that data. My guess is that the data retrieval might be faster using Redis, but now the decoding takes a large amount of time. Python is not the fastest for these kind of things. To get the 100% accurate answer you will have to profile your code!